# Exchange data info between 1 list and 1 element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two (or n) main sections, each section when clicked displays a list of 6 subsections, one is displayed in the main content area, the other 5 remains visible at the bottom.

When you click in one of the other 5, the content (image + title) should be exchanged and the main content section should now have the data from the clicked link and the link the information that was in the content.

So the subsection list should be able to change positions.

I'm new in knockout.js and I thought in some ways to accomplish this, however I would like to be pointed in the right direction when it come to best practices so I can have a good code from the beginning of this project.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the documentation for [foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) and [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) bindings will be helpful.

I would create a function that can be reused for n main sections. This function would have an `ko.observableArray` which would contain a function for the sections. when you click a section it would set that value of an `ko.observable` to the section.

```
    function MainSection() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedSection = ko.observable();
    self.sections = ko.observableArray(
        [
            new Section("Some Data"),
            new Section("Some Data"),
            new Section("Some Data"),
            new Section("Some Data"),
            new Section("Some Data"),
            new Section("Some Data")
        ]);
    self.selectSection = function(item) { //where item is a Section
        self.selectedSection(item);       //passed from the click binding
    };
}
```